# What is causing my camera to zoom in on my character? [unity]

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having a few strange issues with the way my camera is working.  I am trying to do a perspective view of the player to allow for multiple layers to act like a parallaxing effect.

Here is the code I am using on the camera.  ( I have dragged the Player onto the Transform target)

```
public Transform target;
public float distance = 3.0f;
public float height = 3.0f;
public float damping = 5.0f;
public bool followBehind = true;
public float rotationDamping = 10.0f;

void Update()
{
    Vector3 wantedPosition;
    if (followBehind)
        wantedPosition = target.TransformPoint(0, height, -distance);
    else
        wantedPosition = target.TransformPoint(0, height, distance);

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, wantedPosition, Time.deltaTime * damping);

}
```

Here is what is happening:[image]

If you look at the Scale it is set to .5 , but when I press play it looks like this:
[image]

My ultimate goal is to follow the player.  Be some distance away and then be able to adjust the height of the camera, so that my player is towards the ground.  Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wantedPosition` probably has a different **z axis** and is changing the **z axis** of your camera. I suggest you get the **z axis** of the camera then store it  somewhere else. Always change the z axis of `wantedPosition` to that default value before assigning it to the camera.

```
public Transform target;
public float distance = 3.0f;
public float height = 3.0f;
public float damping = 5.0f;
public bool followBehind = true;
public float rotationDamping = 10.0f;

float defaultZPos = 0;

void Start()
{
    Vector3 tempCamPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
    defaultZPos = tempCamPos.z;
}


void Update()
{
    Vector3 wantedPosition;
    if (followBehind)
        wantedPosition = target.TransformPoint(0, height, -distance);
    else
        wantedPosition = target.TransformPoint(0, height, distance);

    //Change the z pos to the deafult vale
    wantedPosition.z = defaultZPos;
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, wantedPosition, Time.deltaTime * damping);

}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That helped.  I also simplified the code to keep things more easy to read.

Comment: @TimCooley I noticed that. One thing more is that you don't need to put [unity] in the topic of your question. That's what the tags are for. If you provide a tag, people will know now that the question is for unity.